# iOS 8.4 UIActivityIndicatorView rendering

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiactivityindicatorview, ios8.4

It seems something is going wrong with `UIActivityIndicatorView`s in iOS 8.4...

How it looks on 8.2:

[image: Activity indicator on iOS 8.2]

How it looks on 8.4:

[image: Activity indicator on iOS 8.4]

If you look closely you'll see that on iOS 8.4 it seems to be rendering at non-retina scale! The same also seems to be happening to badge views on the tab bar, try setting the `badgeValue` on a `UITabBarItem`.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround to get it to draw properly? I know it's only a minor bug but it looks kinda crappy :(

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.